# undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass when importing Bootstrap into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

Getting error:

```
undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

<head>
  <title>Dossiyadata</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

when importing bootstrap. Not sure why?
Using ruby 2.1.1

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Trace:

```
sass-rails (4.0.1) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:84:in `evaluate'
sass-rails (4.0.1) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:70:in `engine_from_path'
sass-rails (4.0.1) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:35:in `find'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:54:in `block in import'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:53:in `each'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:53:in `import'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:283:in `visit_import'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:152:in `block in visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/stack.rb:121:in `with_frame'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:152:in `visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:161:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:173:in `with_environment'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit_children'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:180:in `visit_root'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:151:in `visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
sass (3.3.3) lib/sass/engine.rb:274:in `render'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/sass_template.rb:53:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:37:in `init_with'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/asset.rb:24:in `from_hash'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:54:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.12.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:144:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:113:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:112:in `map'
sprockets-rails (2.0.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:112:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1423391532774445026_70293092038340'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2314247768823616456__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4039488794408656604__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
passenger (4.0.38) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
passenger (4.0.38) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:142:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (4.0.38) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
passenger (4.0.38) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

My style.scss.css file:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

I have inlcued the javascript files, but nothing changes. Not sure why this is happening, any ideas?

**Update**
Found a temporary solution: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/560
Just need to force sprockets version by adding this to gem file: 
`gem 'sprockets', '=2.11.0' #force for now` 
That will fix it for now

Comment: We need more information about the error.

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Edited, I also found this but pretty lost: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails/issues/54

Comment: Have you included your JS files? This is the suggestion in the Github link you sent :)

Comment: do you include //= require bootstrap in your application.js?

Comment: I did include the js files, no change

Comment: another github ticket to tracking this error [sass-rails#191](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/191)

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. A tough one to track down. The answer from Chuanpin Zhu fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I also met that exact same error after I upgraded rails from 4.0.3 to 4.0.4.

To solve solve this problem, only add

```
gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.2"
```

to your Gemfile and then

```
bundle install
```

Finally **restart rails server**

Then enjoy your programming in rails 4.0.4

Comment: I experienced the same problem but when using the rails_admin gem (0.6.1) and upgraded Rails from 4.0.2 to 4.0.3. This here fixed it as well, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've been hit twice by this, once when all I did was go to sleep for 8 hours then restart the development server. Does anyone have an answer as to the "why" of this? It's really frustrating and always a SASS issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer. There must be a bug in the newest version of Sprockets and/or Sass and/or Sass-rails. Thank you for answeroing!

Comment: For Rails 4.0.5 I think you'll need gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.3"

Answer (score 8):

When upgrading to Rails 4.0.5 you need to temporarily lock your sprockets at 2.11.x:

```
gem 'sprockets', '<= 2.11.0'
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

The exact error I was getting was:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
```

For more context:

https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/191

https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/537

Comment: This worked for me when getting an `undefined method \`[]' for nil:NilClass` with Rails 3.2.16