# Bundle update creates ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

When I run bundle update on my rails app, I get this error:

ArgumentError at /
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
at

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "style", media: "all"
```

The error persists even when style.scss is blank.

I think updating one of the gems breaks the code, but I have no idea which gem it is.

application.html.haml:

```
%head
  %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "SocialPost - Ship for Less"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "style", media: "all"
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
  = csrf_meta_tags
```

diff of Gemfile.lock:

```
diff --git a/Gemfile.lock b/Gemfile.lock
index 1fe4528..1696aa8 100644
--- a/Gemfile.lock
+++ b/Gemfile.lock
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ GIT

 GIT
   remote: https://github.com/jordanbrock/bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails.git
-  revision: 91289922bfa61477af1a812f13541a12db5c8591
+  revision: c15e355432d0292dbce0dc9aca5ab79f12d333b6
   specs:
     bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails (0.0.8)
       railties (>= 3.1)
@@ -39,12 +39,12 @@ GEM
       multi_json (~> 1.3)
       thread_safe (~> 0.1)
       tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
-    addressable (2.3.5)
-    annotate (2.6.1)
+    addressable (2.3.6)
+    annotate (2.6.2)
       activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
       rake (>= 0.8.7)
     arel (4.0.2)
-    atomic (1.1.14)
+    atomic (1.1.16)
     awesome_print (1.2.0)
     bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
     better_errors (1.1.0)
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@ GEM
       erubis (>= 2.6.6)
     binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
       debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
-    bootstrap-sass (3.1.0.2)
+    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
       sass (~> 3.2)
     builder (3.1.4)
     capistrano (2.15.5)
@@ -67,9 +67,9 @@ GEM
       rack (>= 1.0.0)
       rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
       xpath (~> 2.0)
-    childprocess (0.4.0)
+    childprocess (0.5.2)
       ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
-    chunky_png (1.2.9)
+    chunky_png (1.3.0)
     clamp (0.6.3)
     climate_control (0.0.3)
       activesupport (>= 3.0)
@@ -84,58 +84,66 @@ GEM
       execjs
     coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
     columnize (0.3.6)
-    compass (0.12.2)
+    compass (0.12.4)
       chunky_png (~> 1.2)
       fssm (>= 0.2.7)
-      sass (~> 3.1)
-    compass-rails (1.1.3)
+      sass (~> 3.2.17)
+    compass-rails (1.1.6)
       compass (>= 0.12.2)
     countries (0.9.3)
       currencies (~> 0.4.2)
     country_select (1.3.1)
       countries (= 0.9.3)
-    cucumber (1.3.10)
+    cucumber (1.3.13)
       builder (>= 2.1.2)
       diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
       gherkin (~> 2.12)
       multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
-      multi_test (>= 0.0.2)
+      multi_test (>= 0.1.1)
     currencies (0.4.2)
     daemons (1.1.9)
     database_cleaner (1.2.0)
-    datagrid (1.0.5)
+    datagrid (1.1.2)
       rails (>= 3.0)
     debug_inspector (0.0.2)
-    debugger (1.6.5)
+    debugger (1.6.6)
       columnize (>= 0.3.1)
       debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
-      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.1)
+      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.2)
     debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
-    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.1)
+    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.2)
     diff-lcs (1.2.5)
     erubis (2.7.0)
     eventmachine (1.0.3)
-    excon (0.31.0)
+    excon (0.32.1)
     execjs (2.0.2)
-    factory_girl (4.3.0)
+    factory_girl (4.4.0)
       activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
-    factory_girl_rails (4.3.0)
-      factory_girl (~> 4.3.0)
+    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
+      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
       railties (>= 3.0.0)
-    faker (1.2.0)
+    faker (1.3.0)
       i18n (~> 0.5)
     faraday (0.9.0)
       multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
     ffi (1.9.3)
-    fog (1.20.0)
+    fog (1.21.0)
+      fog-brightbox
+      fog-core (~> 1.21, >= 1.21.1)
+      fog-json
+      nokogiri (~> 1.5, >= 1.5.11)
+    fog-brightbox (0.0.1)
+      fog-core
+      fog-json
+    fog-core (1.21.1)
       builder
-      excon (~> 0.31.0)
+      excon (~> 0.32)
       formatador (~> 0.2.0)
       mime-types
-      multi_json (~> 1.0)
       net-scp (~> 1.1)
       net-ssh (>= 2.1.3)
-      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11)
+    fog-json (1.0.0)
+      multi_json (~> 1.0)
     formatador (0.2.4)
     fssm (0.2.10)
     gelf (1.4.0)
@@ -156,9 +164,9 @@ GEM
       railties (~> 4.0.0)
     hashie (2.0.5)
     high_voltage (2.1.0)
-    highline (1.6.20)
+    highline (1.6.21)
     hike (1.2.3)
-    httparty (0.12.0)
+    httparty (0.13.0)
       json (~> 1.8)
       multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
     i18n (0.6.9)
@@ -167,8 +175,8 @@ GEM
     jquery-rails (3.1.0)
       railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
       thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
-    jquery-ui-rails (4.1.1)
-      railties (>= 3.1.0)
+    jquery-ui-rails (4.2.0)
+      railties (>= 3.2.16)
     json (1.8.1)
     jwt (0.1.11)
       multi_json (>= 1.5)
@@ -182,7 +190,7 @@ GEM
       treetop (~> 1.4.8)
     method_source (0.8.2)
     mime-types (1.25.1)
-    mini_portile (0.5.2)
+    mini_portile (0.5.3)
     minitest (4.7.5)
     monetize (0.1.4)
     money (6.0.1)
@@ -193,8 +201,8 @@ GEM
       money (~> 6.0.0)
       railties (>= 3.0)
     mono_logger (1.1.0)
-    multi_json (1.8.4)
-    multi_test (0.0.3)
+    multi_json (1.9.2)
+    multi_test (0.1.1)
     multi_xml (0.5.5)
     multipart-post (2.0.0)
     net-scp (1.1.2)
@@ -226,14 +234,14 @@ GEM
       multi_json
       omniauth (~> 1.0)
       omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.1)
-    open4 (1.3.0)
-    paperclip (4.1.0)
+    open4 (1.3.3)
+    paperclip (4.1.1)
       activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
       activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
       cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
       mime-types
     pg (0.17.1)
-    polyglot (0.3.3)
+    polyglot (0.3.4)
     pry (0.9.12.6)
       coderay (~> 1.0)
       method_source (~> 0.8)
@@ -263,24 +271,24 @@ GEM
       activesupport (= 4.0.0)
       rake (>= 0.8.7)
       thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
-    rake (10.1.1)
+    rake (10.2.1)
     rdoc (4.1.1)
       json (~> 1.4)
     redis (3.0.7)
     redis-namespace (1.4.1)
       redis (~> 3.0.4)
     ref (1.0.5)
-    resque (1.25.1)
+    resque (1.25.2)
       mono_logger (~> 1.0)
       multi_json (~> 1.0)
-      redis-namespace (~> 1.2)
+      redis-namespace (~> 1.3)
       sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
       vegas (~> 0.1.2)
-    rspec-core (2.14.7)
+    rspec-core (2.14.8)
     rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
       diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
-    rspec-mocks (2.14.5)
-    rspec-rails (2.14.1)
+    rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
+    rspec-rails (2.14.2)
       actionpack (>= 3.0)
       activemodel (>= 3.0)
       activesupport (>= 3.0)
@@ -288,7 +296,7 @@ GEM
       rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
       rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
       rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
-    rubber (2.7.1)
+    rubber (2.7.4)
       capistrano (~> 2.12)
       clamp
       fog (~> 1.6)
@@ -296,8 +304,8 @@ GEM
       net-ssh (~> 2.6)
       open4
       thor
-    rubyzip (1.1.0)
-    sass (3.2.14)
+    rubyzip (1.1.2)
+    sass (3.2.18)
     sass-rails (4.0.1)
       railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
       sass (>= 3.1.10)
@@ -305,8 +313,8 @@ GEM
     sdoc (0.4.0)
       json (~> 1.8)
       rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
-    selenium-webdriver (2.39.0)
-      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
+    selenium-webdriver (2.40.0)
+      childprocess (>= 0.5.0)
       multi_json (~> 1.0)
       rubyzip (~> 1.0)
       websocket (~> 1.0.4)
@@ -317,8 +325,8 @@ GEM
       rack (~> 1.4)
       rack-protection (~> 1.4)
       tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.4)
-    slop (3.4.7)
-    sprockets (2.10.1)
+    slop (3.5.0)
+    sprockets (2.12.0)
       hike (~> 1.2)
       multi_json (~> 1.0)
       rack (~> 1.0)
@@ -330,19 +338,19 @@ GEM
     therubyracer (0.12.1)
       libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
       ref
-    thin (1.6.1)
+    thin (1.6.2)
       daemons (>= 1.0.9)
       eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
       rack (>= 1.0.0)
-    thor (0.18.1)
-    thread_safe (0.1.3)
-      atomic
+    thor (0.19.1)
+    thread_safe (0.3.1)
+      atomic (>= 1.1.7, < 2)
     tilt (1.4.1)
     treetop (1.4.15)
       polyglot
       polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
-    tzinfo (0.3.38)
-    uglifier (2.4.0)
+    tzinfo (0.3.39)
+    uglifier (2.5.0)
       execjs (>= 0.3.0)
       json (>= 1.8.0)
     vegas (0.1.11)
```

Comment: Try renaming your "style.scss" to "style.css". Aren't you using the default "application.css"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, with Rails 4.0.3. The error was caused by compass. I removed compass and used [bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) instead. Problem solved!

I also had to update sass-rails after receiving the error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426698/undefined-method-environment-for-nilnilclass-when-importing-bootstrap-into-ra).

Comment: how easy would it be to switch? I have existing compass code I am using throughout the project...

Comment: No need to switch, just use correct gems (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22839587/2637573))

Answer (score 3):

As 'arogos' points out the problem is related to compass, but the main issue is caused by the **sass-rails** gem. **sass-rails 4.0.2** depends on **sass ~> 3.2.0**, whereas **4.0.1** allowed **sass >= 3.1.10**. However, **compass 1.0** needs **sass 3.3**. To make everything work again you need this gem combination:

```
gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.1.7'
```

To use **sass 3.3** and **compass 1.0** you have to wait for a rewrite of sass-rails (see [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/pull/192))

Comment: I only had to change it so the version of `sass-rails` was `4.0.2`. I'm sure there are situations where perhaps you may need to change the others too.

Comment: Yes, you probably only have to change the other gems, if you already had installed compass 1.0 (it worked with sass-rails 4.0.1). Then your bundle depended on sass 3.3.